# How to grab part of a URL string using get feature to dynamically insert into a tracker?

Tags: php, get

I was wondering, I searched but couldn't find exactly what I need.

I need to track a variable in a URL string, grab it, then insert into my form code to be able to track a lead.

For example, in the ad I am buying, I can dynamically insert the publisher ID into the URL string so I can track if that website converts, such as http://mywebsite.com/?c1=[csid]

where [csid] will be replaced by the website that converts so it turns into http://mywebsite.com/?c1=www.anywebsite.com

I need to grab the c1 value of "www.anywebsite.com" and dynamically insert it into my php code so that I can see what that value was that converted.

Hope that make sense

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTTP GET variables, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

```
<?php
$c1 = $_GET['c'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of "c1", with this expression:

```
$c1 = $_REQUEST['c1']
```

But without further information I can't really help you on storing it, unless you specify the way you intend to use it.

Hope it helps,
A.

Comment: so if the end of my url is http://mywebsite.com?c1=[csid] where [csid] is a dynamic variable the ad network inserts, could I then in my html have tracker=$c1 = $_REQUEST['c1'] which will then replace it with [csid] variable?, I think that does help, but, what is the rest of the php code I would use along side of that?  Sorry am a newbie with php